# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' error

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie. For a school project, I need a typewriter, and I came down to this idea that seems good to me. But when I launch it, it says this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' error
```

I don't know why. I think the idea is good, because when I try without the variable `t`, so just putting numbers in `testo.erase()`, it works, but I need to create a loop.

```cpp
void typewriter(string testo, int tempo)
{
    int i = testo.length();
    int t = 0;
    while (t<=i)
    {
        system ("CLS");
        t=t+1;
        testo.erase(t);
        cout<<testo;
        Sleep(tempo);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (t<=i)` => `while (t<i)` Read again about indexing ranges please! Also erasing elements from a container while iterating through it isn't a very clever idea.

Comment: you are also adding one to t and erasing that. there could be nothing at t+1 you must check if it exists

Comment: It's worse than just an off-by-one, they are actively shrinking the string in the loop, but still using the original length.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: Don't *ever* use `system()`. It's a security nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are erasing the characters, which shortens the string. I think that changing `testo.erase(t)` to `test.erase(0)` should fix it.

Also, as πάντα ῥεῖ said, it should be `t < i` instead of `t <= i`. But, this is an unnecessary change, as with the erasing of characters.

Comment: `t < i` is an insufficient change specifically because they are removing a character at every iteration.

Comment: so when it erases, it changes totally the string?

Comment: @Epic. Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I resolved it by reassigning the string `testo` every time I join in the `while` loop:

```cpp
void typewriter(string testo, int tempo)
{
    int i = testo.length();
    int t = 0;
    string testo1 = testo;
    while (t<i)
    {
        testo1 = testo;
        system ("CLS");
        t=t+1;
        testo1.erase(t);
        cout<<testo1;
        Sleep(tempo);
    }
}
```